# Deleting multiple rows in Django frontend

Tags: django, view, delete-row

I am going to implment a multi delete (via select boxes) view in django.

I know there's a view in django.contrib.admin.actions but I can't port this to frontend.

Should I assign object id's in the form and POST these to my delete view and then use .delete() ?

I haven't been programming before, and Django is the framework I start my programming adventure.

I was looking for example (for Django view + html) but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [`modelformset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) and manually rendering the form with just the `delete` options: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#manually-rendered-can-delete-and-can-order

Alternative solution:

Using a [`modelformset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) to create a bunch of forms with a delete checkbox like this:

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    id = fields.IntegerField(widget=widgets.HiddenInputField)
    delete = fields.BooleanField(required=False)

    def save(self, commit=False):
        if self.is_valid() and self.cleaned_data['delete']:
            self.instance.delete()             

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
```

Comment: I see there's a can_delete option which adds the "delete" booleanfield.. will take a look, thanks!

Comment: @Robert: ah, you're right... I've never even seen that one :)