# Django: writing a view to delete multiple object with checkboxes

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox, django-views

So I have a table that lists all the record from my model.
But now I'm trying to make a Checkbox and delete it (kinda like the Django admin way), I can't find the documentation for this , as I'm sure there are several ways to to this.
But I'm trying to figure out like whats the proper way for doing this , should I do this via view ?

How to create single delete button  for  multiple delete instances in html and view.I am not using form
I refreed this side but not get correct solution 
[Django: writing a view to delete an item with checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897291/django-writing-a-view-to-delete-an-item-with-checkboxes)
[Deleting multiple rows in Django frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496551/deleting-multiple-rows-in-django-frontend)

**list.html**

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"  name="data" value="{{obj.id}}" ></td>
            <td><a href='#' data-toggle="collapse" value="{{obj.id}}">{{ obj.id }}</td>
            <td><a href='#demo' data-toggle="collapse">{{ obj.Full_Name }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">{{ obj.Agency_Name}}</a></td>
            <td><a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">{{ obj.Date_of_Birth}}</a></td>
            <td><a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse">{{ obj.Agency_Code}}</a></td>
            <td><a href="#demo" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="label label-primary">{{ obj.Agent_Status}}</span></a></td>

            <td class="text-right">
                <a  href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-circle" type="button"><i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <a  href="{% url 'customer:Agent_Edit'  obj.id %}" class="btn btn-info btn-circle" type="button"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                #<a  href="{% url 'customer:Agent_Delete'  obj.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                #Remove this button and create single button for multiple delete
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
{% endfor %}
```

**view.py**

```
def Agent_List(request, id=None): #list items
  queryset =  Agent.objects.order_by('id')
  #queryset = Agent.objects.all()   
  query = request.GET.get('q')
  if query:
    queryset=queryset.filter(
            Q(Aadhaar_Number__icontains=query) |
            Q(PAN_Number__icontains=query) |
            Q(Account_Number__icontains=query) 
            ).distinct()
  context = {
    "object_list": queryset, 
    "Full_Name ": "Agent_List",

  }
  return  render(request, "customer/Agent_List.html", context)

def Agent_Delete(request, id=None):
  instance = get_object_or_404(Agent, id=id)
  instance.delete()
  messages.success(request, "Successfully deleted")
  return redirect("customer:Agent_List")
```

In def Agent_Delete(request, id=None) it delete single id.but How to delete selected multiple id.Thank you in advance.

Comment: I will suggest ajax method to delete. Write an ajax method, pass document id and run the view.

Comment: i didnot ajax ,please tell the how get the checkbox value in view and how apply delete